# Not able to integrate testng with gradle. Error while building jar

Tags: gradle, testng

I am new to gradle. Trying to integrate the testNG with Gradle and want to create jar file using "gradle build" command
This is how my build.gradle looks like

---

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                    'Main-Class': 'org.testng.TestNG'
       }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

dependencies {
     testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
}

test {
    useTestNG(){
    include '**/*'
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'repos'
       }
    }
}
```

---

However when I run the "gradle build" command I am getting following error for each testNG annotation

: error: cannot find symbol
     @Test
      ^
Symbol:   class Test
Location: class helloWorld